# Is it possible to change the default encoding in notepad?

Tags: windows, encoding, notepad, ansi

On windows 7 (x64), the default option, for saving text files in notepad is ANSI.
One can select other encoding from the combo box, however, I'd like this option to be the default.

Comment: Here simplest fix - http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Notepad-Default-UTF-8-Unicode-Creator.shtml
(It will automatically associate UTF8 with Notepad. No need to install anything, just run once )

Answer (score 13):

Idea for saving it in UTF-8 by default, haven't found a different encoding way as default.

1. `Right click -> New -> Text Document`
2. Open it, and do **NOT** type anything into it.
3. Go to `File -> Save As...` and choose UTF-8 under `Encoding`, press `Save` and overwrite existing file. Close the file.
4. Rename `New Text Document.txt` to `TXTUTF-8.txt`
5. Copy `TXTUTF-8.txt` to `C:\WINDOWS\SHELLNEW`
6. Go to "Start -> Run..." and type regedit. Press OK.
7. Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew`
8. Right click in the right window -> New -> `String Value` and rename it to `FileName`
9. Double click on `FileName` and put `TXTUTF-8.txt` into value data field and press OK.
10. Test it: Create new .txt document (Right click -> New -> Text Document). Open it and go to `File -> Save As...` and see look at the encoding to make sure it defaults to UTF-8.

Comment: It accomplishes its purpose well, however, sometime, I find myself starting new file with no intentions of saving it, and ending up with something that I'd like to save.
That's usually when I encounter that problem, and if I'm not careful enough when saving, it can destroy a document written in a foreign language...

It's all a matter of habits, but I hoped there might be some way to change it permanently.

Comment: Is there any one-click solution?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, of course that's why is not marked as answer.

Answer (score 6):

In windows 7 (perhaps other systems as well) you need to set the system locale - regional settings > administrative tab > change system locale to the language of your choice. This solved my problem of Hebrew fonts not displaying properly in notepad.