# Force UTF-8 on every document opened in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, character-encoding, utf-8

I want every document that I create or open in Notepad++ to always (no matter what) be encoded in UTF-8. It seems, that either I'm missing something or this is not possible.

In `Settings > Preferences... > New Document > Encoding` I have `UTF-8 without BOM` selected in the list plus `Apply to opened  ANSI files` checked as well. I'm using version [6.7.4](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.7.4-je-suis-charlie-edition.html).

Everyhing is fine, when I create a new file directly in Notepad++. Then, yes, it has UTF-8 w/o BOM encoding set by default. But, when I select `New > Text Document` in Windows Explorer, create a new empty text file and then double click it, it opens in Notepad++ with `ANSI` encoding by default.

What is wrong? For me, option `Apply to opened  ANSI files` seems to be not working at all.

Comment: Perhaps you need to realize that (what Windows incorrectly calls) ANSI and UTF-8 are identical if your text doesn't contain any actual explicit UTF-8 characters.  So if Notepad++ opens it and detects its character endoding, it doesn't really matter if it's UTF-8 or "ANSI" if the file is pure ASCII (as in, for instance, English text, or usually, source code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. It is just, how Notepad++ is working. Files are actually saved as UTF-8 w/o BOM.

Whenever an ANSI-encoded text file is opened in Notepad++, editor displays its correct encoding (ANSI). However, after actually saving that file, it will be saved as UTF-8 w/o BOM, if `Apply to opened  ANSI files` option is checked. To verify this, one must create a new text file in the Windows Explorer, open it in Notepad++, change contents, save and reopen. It will be recognized as encoded in UTF-8 w/o BOM.

Tip: There's a fairy easy way to force Windows Notepad to always save files in UTF-8:

- solution at [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/default-utf-8-encoding-for-new-notepad-documents/525f0ae7-121e-4eac-a6c2-cfe6b498712c),
- solution at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/872848/74576).

It requires some tweaks in Windows registry, but allows you to have all files always encoded in UTF-8, no matter, what editor you're using.

Comment: Fails for me, I think. I have a file containing Unicode characters. It displays as pairs of hex digits instead of the Unicode. The status line says "Windows (CR LF)   UCS-2 LE BOM". I want to see it in Unicode glyphs.