# In Windows 8, how do I change the default encoding from ANSI to Unicode in Notepad?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, encoding, notepad

I followed the guidance in this Super User question:
[Windows 7 - Changing the default ANSI to UTF-8 in Notepad](https://superuser.com/questions/557023/changing-the-default-ansi-to-utf-8-in-notepad).

However, I don't have the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew`.

How can I change the default encoding from ANSI to Unicode in Notepad
with Windows 8 Pro?

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer a cheap alternative fix... hear me out: Create a blank txt file and resave it as Unicode. Close it. Enter the file's properties and check the read-only attribute:

[image: file properties, read-only]

Then every time you want to create a new Unicode file, instead of opening Notepad, open that specific file. When you try to save, it will force a save-as, and the encoding will default to Unicode.